# CloudKit: Get users firstname/surname

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I'm trying to get the users first name using cloud kit however the following code is not getting the users first name and is leaving firstNameFromFunction variable empty. Does anyone know how to achieve this in iOS 10?

```
let container = CKContainer.default()        
container.fetchUserRecordID { (recordId, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Handle error)")
            }else{

                self.container.discoverUserInfo(
                    withUserRecordID: recordId!, completionHandler: { (userInfo, error) in
                        if error != nil {
                            print("Handle error")
                        }else{
                            if let userInfo = userInfo {
                                print("givenName =   \(userInfo.displayContact?.givenName)")
                                print("familyName = \(userInfo.displayContact?.familyName)")
                                firstNameFromFunction = userInfo.displayContact?.givenName
                            }else{
                                print("no user info")
                            }
                        }
                })
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

the permission screen that comes up when asking for the first time, IMO, is very poorly worded. They need to change that. It says "Allow people using 'your app' to look you up by email? People who know your email address will be able to see that you use this app." This make NO sense. This has nothing to do with asking the user to get their iCloud first name, last name, email address.

Speaking of email address - this and the phone number from the lookupInfo property is missing - i.e. set to nil, even though those values are legit and correct. Filing a bug tonight.

Answer (score 1):

First, you will need to request permission to access the user's information.

Then, you can use a CKDiscoverUserIdentitiesOperation. This is just like any other CKOperation (eg. the modify record operation). You just need to create a new operation with the useridentitylookupinfo. Then you will also need to create a completion block to handle the results.

Here is an example function I created:

```
    func getUserName(withRecordID recordID: CKRecordID,
                 completion: @escaping (String) -> ()) {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let userInfo = CKUserIdentityLookupInfo(userRecordID: recordID)
        let discoverOperation = CKDiscoverUserIdentitiesOperation(userIdentityLookupInfos: [userInfo])
        discoverOperation.userIdentityDiscoveredBlock = { (userIdentity, userIdentityLookupInfo) in
            let userName = "\((userIdentity.nameComponents?.givenName ?? "")) \((userIdentity.nameComponents?.familyName ?? ""))"
            completion(userName)
        }
        discoverOperation.completionBlock = {
            completion("")
        }
        CKContainer.default().add(discoverOperation)
    } else {
        // iOS 10 and below version of the code above,
        // no longer works. So, we just return an empty string.
        completion("")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to ask the user for permission to be discovered.

Use `CKContainer.default().requestApplicationPermission` method passing .userDiscoverability on applicationPermission parameter.

The `CKContainer.default().discoverUserInfo` method is deprecated on iOS 10. Instead use `CKContainer.default().discoverUserIdentity method.`

Do something like:

```
CKContainer.default().requestApplicationPermission(.userDiscoverability) { (status, error) in
                    CKContainer.default().fetchUserRecordID { (record, error) in
                        CKContainer.default().discoverUserIdentity(withUserRecordID: record!, completionHandler: { (userIdentity, error) in

                            print("\(userIdentity?.nameComponents?.givenName)")
                            print("\(userIdentity?.nameComponents?.familyName)")

                        })
                    }
                }
```

Comment: When i execute that line of code, nothing is  printed on the screen, and variable first name (i added) is still set to nil

Comment: If you already asked the user permission using a physical device logged into an iCloud account and still could not print the user information, I do not know what that could be. I tested with an iPhone using XCode 8.1 and it worked fine.